# How to use XML::LibXML to parse an XML document and build a Perl hash

Tags: perl

I have XML data that will be like this

```
<Root>
  <Bag Identifier="1">
    <Code Amount="0" Code="XA" Conversion="0" Currency="INR" Desc="" Id="1"/>
  </Bag>
  <Bag Identifier="2">
    <Code Amount="21" Code="XA" Conversion="0" Currency="INR" Desc="" Id="2"/>
  </Bag>
</Root>
```

I want to parse this and create a Perl hash as below. The `Identifier` attribute of each `Bag` element should be the primary hash key.

```
'2' => {
  'Amount' => "21",
  'Code' => "XA",
  'Currency' => "INR",
}
'1' => {
  'Amount' => "0",
  'Code' => "XA",
  'Currency' => "INR",
}
```

This is my Perl code

```
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xml_doc = $parser->parse_string($response);

my $test_node = $xml_doc->findnodes('//Bag/');
print Dumper($test_node);

print $test_node->find('@Id')->string_value();
```

How can I create the hash that I have described?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: yes i am not able to read the values and create the same hash structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This program does as you ask. It reads a copy of your sample data from the `DATA` file handle, and uses `Data::Dump` to display the resultant data structure.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $data = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => \*DATA);

my %data;

my @bags = $data->findnodes('/Root/Bag');

for my $bag (@bags) {

  my $id = $bag->getAttribute('Identifier');

  my ($code) = $bag->getChildrenByTagName('Code');

  my %item;
  for my $attr (qw/ Amount Code Currency /) {
    $item{$attr} = $code->getAttribute($attr);
  }
  $data{$id} = \%item;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%data;

__DATA__
<Root>
  <Bag Identifier="1">
    <Code Amount="0" Code="XA" Conversion="0" Currency="INR" Desc="" Id="1"/>
  </Bag>
  <Bag Identifier="2">
    <Code Amount="21" Code="XA" Conversion="0" Currency="INR" Desc="" Id="2"/>
  </Bag>
</Root>
```

**output**

```
{
  1 => { Amount => 0, Code => "XA", Currency => "INR" },
  2 => { Amount => 21, Code => "XA", Currency => "INR" },
}
```