# Perl Hash using LibXML

Tags: perl, libxml2

I have an XML data as follows.

```
<type>
   <data1>something1</data1>
   <data2>something2</data2>
</type>
<type>
   <data1>something1</data1>
   <data2>something2</data2>
</type>
<type>
   <data1>something1</data1>
</type>
```

As one can see, child node data2 is sometimes not present.

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27328986/how-to-use-xmllibxml-to-parse-an-xml-document-and-build-a-perl-hash) as a guideline to create the following code.

```
my %hash;
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc    = $parser->parse_file($file_name);
my @nodes  = $doc->findnodes("/type");

foreach my $node(@nodes)
{
    my $key = $node->getChildrenByTagName('data1');
    my $value = $node->getChildrenByTagName('data2');
    $hash{$key} = $value;
}
```

Later, I am using this hash to generate some more data based on a fact if the child node data2 is present or not.

I use `ne` operator assuming that data in the `%hash` are key value pairs of strings and when `data2` is not present, Perl inserts space as a value in the hash (I have printed this hash and found that only space is printed as a value).

However, I end up with following compilation errors.

```
Operation "ne": no method found,
        left argument in overloaded package XML::LibXML::NodeList,
        right argument has no overloaded magic at filename.pl line 74.
```

How do I solve this? What is the best data structure to store this data when we see that sometimes a node will not be there ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing to realize is `$value` is an XML::LibXML::NodeList object.  It only looks like a string when you print it because it has stringification overloaded.  You can check with `ref $value`.

With `my $value = $node->getChildrenByTagName('data2');`, `$value` will *always* be a NodeList object.  It might be an empty NodeList, but you'll always get a NodeList object.

---

Your version of XML::LibXML is out of date.  Your version of XML::LibXML::NodeList has no string comparison overloading and, by default, Perl will not "fallback" to use stringification for other string operators like `ne`.  [I reported this bug back in 2010](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=57737) and it was [fixed in 2011 in version 1.77](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/XML-LibXML#L543).

Upgrade XML::LibXML and the problem will go away.

As a work around you can force stringification by quoting the NodeList object.

```
if( "$nodelist" ne "foo" ) { ... }
```

But really, update that module.  There's been a lot of work done on it.

> Perl inserts space as a value in the hash

This is a NodeList object stringifying.  I get an empty string from an empty NodeList.  You might be getting a space as an old bug.

You can also check `$value->size` to see if the NodeList is empty.

Comment: That explains it. I will have to update my libXML 3rd Party library.

Comment: @Recker, it's the Perl module that needs updating, not the libxml library