# Convert XML to Perl Hash

Tags: xml, perl

For the below XML structure, I'm trying to get a corresponding Perl Hash array

```
<root>
  <ref name="abc_sia_%version1.ref%">
    <func envname = "test01" objectdir = "/home/pv66" base="default_771"/>
  </ref>
</root>
```

I am able to turn it into a perl hash using:

```
my $xml = new XML::Simple;
my $data = $xml->XMLin("/home/pv66", ForceArray => 1, KeyAttr => { ref => "name"});
print Dumper ($data);
```

From which the hash turns out to be:

```
$VAR1 = {
           'ref' => {
                       'abc_sia_%version1.ref' => {
                                                      'func' => [
                                                                  {
                                                                   'envname' => 'test01',
                                                                   'objectdir' => '/home/pv66',
                                                                   'base' => 'default_771'
                                                                  }
                                                                ]       
                                                  }
                    }
         };
```

Although I need to remove the upper reference, basically I want the hash to look like:

```
$VAR1 = {
           'abc_sia_%version1.ref' => {
                                         'func' => [
                                                     {
                                                        'envname' => 'test01',
                                                        'objectdir' => '/home/pv66',
                                                        'base' => 'default_771'
                                                     }
                                                   ]       
                                       }
        };
```

Is there any way by which I can transform the hash??

Comment: Suggestion is go with [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) instead of `XML::Simple`.

Comment: @vkk05 Yes I'm aware that LibXML is always suggested, although I was not able to find any particular attribute/function in LibXML that could help me transform it like above. I'd really appreciate if you could shed some light on how to do it using LibXML.

Comment: You haven't found a way using XML::Simple either...  XML doesn't map to hashes/arrays well. You need to say how to do this. XML::Simple doesn't allow you to do this, thus the warning in the module's very own documentation telling you not to use it. Seriously, why are you using a module when the module itself tells you not to?!

Comment: @ikegami Which is why I posted the question. 
I found something very similar:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27328986/how-to-use-xmllibxml-to-parse-an-xml-document-and-build-a-perl-hash

Although if you look at the hash, there's a list in func, which is being achieved from the ForceArray parameter in XML:Simple, is there anything similar in XMLLib?

Comment: You only think XML::Simple works. Sometime later, it won't meet your needs. You can't round-trip the data reliably, for instance. The docs tell you this. But, as ikegami notes, you've only told us what you think a solution is and you haven't said anything about the actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was add another level of search and assign it to a variable. I'm posting the solution anyway:

```
my $xml = new XML::Simple;
my $data = $xml->XMLin("/home/pv66", ForceArray => 1, KeyAttr => { ref => "name"});
my data1 = $data->{'ref'};
print Dumper ($data1);
```

This returns:

```
    $VAR1 = {
           'abc_sia_%version1.ref' => {
                                         'func' => [
                                                     {
                                                        'envname' => 'test01',
                                                        'objectdir' => '/home/pv66',
                                                        'base' => 'default_771'
                                                     }
                                                   ]       
                                       }
        };
```

Which is what I wanted the structure to look like.

Comment: Please stop using indirect object notation in your code. `new XML::Simple` will work most of the time, but when it doesn't you'll waste days tracking down the problem. Far better to use `XML::Simple->new()` (but, obviously, even better to not use XML::Simple at all).

Comment: I note that XML::Simple used to use indirect object notation in its documentation. But that was fixed in version 2.16 - which was released in October 2016. This leads me to believe that you're using a version of the module that is over fifteen years old. Please do yourself a favour and update your development environment.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. Actually I've been working on modernizing some of these, for which I was facing some issues understanding how things work in Perl. From what I know, the scripts I'm changing were written in 2004 :D

Answer (score 3):

The docs for [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) can be a bit terse for beginners. I recommend [Grant's tutorial](https://grantm.github.io/perl-libxml-by-example/) instead.

XML::LibXML doesn't have a single "make a data structure from this XML document" method. As XML::Simple shows, that approach would be too fragile to be useful. Instead, you can walk the DOM yourself to extract whatever data you want into your data structure. Personally, I'm a fan of using XPath expressions to identify what I want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;
use XML::LibXML;

# Here, I've loaded the XML from the DATA filehandle
# (at the end of the source file). Other options are
# available.
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => \*DATA);

my $data;

# Look for all '/root/ref' nodes...
for my $ref ($dom->findnodes('/root/ref')) {
  # Get the name of the ref node
  my $key = $ref->findvalue('./@name');
  my @funcs;
  # Look for all of the 'func' nodes below this ref node
  for my $func ($ref->findnodes('./func')) {
    my $func_data;
    # For each attribute we're interested in...
    for (qw[envname objectdir base]) {
      # Get the value of the attribute
      $func_data->{$_} = $func->findvalue("./\@$_");
    }
    push @funcs, $func_data;
  }
  $data->{$key}{func} = \@funcs;
}

say Dumper $data;

__DATA__
<root>
  <ref name="abc_sia_%version1.ref%">
    <func envname = "test01" objectdir = "/home/pv66" base="default_771"/>
  </ref>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks Dave!! This does make a lot of sense and is indeed very helpful to do basic search and hashing.